# reduced row echelon form and the equation Ax=0

Tags: linear-algebra

Can anyone help me to prove this by using rref:

if A is a square matrix not invertible, then the equation Ax=0 has a non trivial solution.

Thank you.

Comment: If the linear application $f_A$ associated to $A$ is not invertible it is not injective, hence $f_A(u)=f_A(v)$ for some $u\neq v$ and $u-v \in \text{ker} A$.

Comment: well, i want to show this without using the linear application associate to A, thank you my friend for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Jack D'Aurizio's comment is correct.*

[A matrix is invertible if and only if it is injective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862582/is-it-enough-for-linear-transformation-to-be-injective-to-be-invertible).
If $A$ is not injective, then $Au = Av$ for two distinct vectors $u$ and $v$.
By linearity, $Ax=0$ where $x = u - v \neq 0$.

Comment: i know that the answer of Jack is correct, but i want a way to show this by rref. thank you parsiad.

Answer (score 0):

If the matrix $A$ (of dimension $n$) is not invertible, there is a positive integer $r$ such that the *rref* of $A$ can be transformed (swapping some columns, which amounts to re-numbering the unknowns) into a block triangular matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
I_{n-r}&B\\0& 0_{r}
\end{bmatrix},$$
where $I_{n-r}$ is the unit matrix of dimension $n-r$, $ 0_{r}$  the null square matrix of dimension $r$ and $B$ is a $n-r\times r$ matrix. So we obtain the subspace $S$ of solutions is defined by the equations:
\begin{align}
&x_1+b_{11}x_{n-r+1}+\dots+b_{1r}x_{n}=x_2+b_{21}x_{n-r+1}+\dots+b_{2r}x_{n}\\{}={}&\dots=x_{n-r}+b_{n-r\:1}x_{n-r+1}+\dots+b_{n-r\:r}x_{n}=0,
\end{align}
form which we deduce readily $x_1,\dots, x_{n-r}$ as linear functions $\ell_1,\dots,\ell_{n-r}$ of the $r$ free variables $ x_{n-r+1},\dots ,x_{n}$.

This let us define an isomorphism from $K^r$ ($K$ is the base field) to this subspace:
\begin{align}
K^r&\longrightarrow S\\
(x_{n-r+1},\dots ,x_{n})&\longmapsto (\ell_1,\dots,\ell_{n-r},x_{n-r+1},\dots ,x_{n}).
\end{align}

Comment: thank you Bernard for your great answer, but i have a little question her to ask, why the rref of A is in the form above?

Comment: That's the definition of the rref: at most a single $1$ in each column, the rest in the column is $0$.

Comment: but the rref of A can be for instance the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 2& 0 &0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\  0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\0 &0 & 0&0                                                                                            
\end{pmatrix}$$ Am i wrong?

Comment: @AmineElBouzidi: You're right, I took a too particular case. I'll fix tat in a moment.

Comment: @AmineElBouzidi: I've updated my answer. Hope this is clear.